# Does this inequality about the second derivative of logarithm of modified Bessel function hold?

Tags: derivatives, inequality, bessel-functions

In [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6740818/), I came across the statement:

> It is easy to confirm that$$\Bigg(\frac{I'_{\frac{D}{2}-1}(t)}{I_{\frac{D}{2}-1}(t)}\Bigg)'\le 0$$ for all $t > 0$ and $D \ge 2$.

For $I_\nu$ the modified Bessel of first kind, order $\nu$.

By the quotient rule and a few [Bessel identities](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/20/01/02/):

$$\begin{align}
\Bigg(\frac{I'_{\nu}(t)}{I_{\nu}(t)}\Bigg)' &= \frac{I''_\nu(t)I_\nu(t) - (I'_\nu(t))^2}{(I_\nu(t))^2} \\
&=\frac{I''_\nu(t)}{I_\nu(t)} - \Big(\frac{I'_\nu(t)}{I_\nu(t)}\Big)^2 \tag{1}\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\frac{I_{\nu-2}(t) + 2I_{\nu}(t) + I_{\nu+2}(t)}{I_\nu(t)} - \Big(\frac{I_{\nu+1}(t) + \frac{\nu}{x}}{I_\nu(t)}\Big)^2
\end{align}$$

For $\nu=0$:

$$\begin{align}
\Bigg(\frac{I'_{0}(t)}{I_{0}(t)}\Bigg)' &= \frac{1}{4}\frac{ 2I_{0}(t) + 2I_{2}(t)}{I_0(t)} - \Big(\frac{I_{1}(t)}{I_0(t)}\Big)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{I_2(t)}{2I_0(t)} - \Big(\frac{I_{1}(t)}{I_0(t)}\Big)^2
\end{align}$$

Plots of this function show it greater than zero; I've tried several variations of $(1)$ using recurrence formulas, all equivalent and suggesting the inequality holds for orders greater than zero.

Where have I erred?

Answer (score 0):

You can continue with your approach, although using $2I'_{\nu} = I_{\nu+1}+I_{\nu-1}$ is easier: you can then group the terms into three expressions of the form
$$ I_{\mu+1}(x)I_{\mu-1}(x)-I_{\mu}^2(x), $$
which can be shown to be negative by expanding and using the Cauchy product of the series for each Bessel function (See [this page](http://www-old.ias.ac.in/j_archive/proca/33/6/373-384/viewpage.html) of the paper V.R. Thiruvenkatachar, T.S. Nanjundiah, Inequalities concerning Bessel functions and orthogonal polynomials, Proc. Ind. Acad. Sci. Sect. A 33 (1951) 373–384).

However, I believe one can proceed with a similar approach directly. We have
$$ I_{\nu}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{c_{\nu,k}}{k!} \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{k+2\nu}, $$
where $c_{\nu,k} = 1/\Gamma(\nu+k+1)$. Then
$$I_{\nu}'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k+\nu)c_{\nu,k}}{k!} \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{2k+\nu-1} \\
I_{\nu}''(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2k+\nu)(2k+\nu-1)c_{\nu,k}}{k!} \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{2k+\nu-2}, $$
so we have
$$ I_{\nu}''(x)I_{\nu}(x)-I_{\nu}'(x)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^{2n+2\nu-2} \sum_{k+l=n} \frac{2k+\nu}{k!n!}\big( (2l+\nu-1)-(2l+\nu) \big) c_{\nu,k}^2. $$
But every term on the right is nonpositive since the bracket reduces to $-1$.